# Задача "Функция генерации арифметических примеров с ответами"

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Условие: написать функцию, которая будет генерировать арифметические
>   примеры и ответы на них.

Мои мысли:

```
import random
def questionsGeneration():
    number1, number2, arithm, question, answer = 0, 0, '', '', 0
    arithmetic = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    number1 = random.choice(range(10))
    number2 = random.choice(range(10))
    arithm = random.choice(arithmetic)
    question = str(number1) + arithm + str(number2)
    answer = number1 + arithm + number2
    return (question, answers)
```

но при таком подходе, разумеется, не вычисляется answer
Как можно исправить? Лучше чем вот это не смогла придумать:

```
if arithm == '+':
    answer = number1 + number2
elif arithm == '-':
    if number1 > number2:
        answer = number1 - number2
    else:
        answer = number2 - number1
elif arithm == '*':
    answer = number1 * number2
elif arithm == '/':
    if number1 > number2:
        answer = number1 / number2
    else:
        answer = number2 / number1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если чуть-чуть допилить ваш пример, он в принципе рабочий:

```
import random

def questionsGeneration():
    number1, number2, arithm, question, answer = 0, 0, '', '', 0
    arithmetic = {
        "+": lambda x, y: x + y,
        "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
        "*": lambda x, y: x * y,
        "/": lambda x, y: x / y,
    }
    number1 = random.choice(range(1, 11))
    number2 = random.choice(range(1, 11))
    arithm = random.choice(list(arithmetic.keys()))
    question = str(number1) + str(arithm) + str(number2)
    answer = arithmetic[arithm](number1, number2)
    return (question, answer)
```

Я просто не понимаю из задания, насколько вам надо сложные и какие примеры приводить.
Для элементарных - можно как я сделал выше. Для полноценных примеров, например: `n1+n2*(n3-n1)/123` - вам надо писать токенайзер, лексический и семантические анализаторы, которые будут генерировать примеры и выполнять их.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Подобные задачи (и особенно более сложные) удобно решать с помощью пакета символьной математики [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/ru/) или, если это учебная задача/свой личный проект, даже с помощью простого [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Но можно и использовать ассоциацию символов математических операторов и соответсвующих им функций, как реализовано в соседнем ответе @Axenow. Опубликую ответ, основанный на том же принципе, с применением внутренней библиотеки `operator` и обработкой ошибки деления на ноль, а также реализацией требования ТС *вычитание из большего, деление большего*.

```
from random import choice
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv


def switcher(op):
    '''
    Декоратор для вычитания и деления
    Выполняет сравнение операндов и перестановку
    Первый операнд >= второй операнд
    '''
    def wrapper(a, b):
        no_switch = a >= b
        try:
            return (op(a, b), False) if no_switch else (op(b, a), True)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            # При делении на ноль возвращается None
            return None, not no_switch
    return wrapper


def noop_wrap(op):
    '''
    Пустой декоратор для умножения и сложения
    Просто добавляет один возвращаемый параметр False,
    обозначающий, что операнды не меняются местами
    '''
    def wrapper(*args):
        return op(*args), False
    return wrapper


def pair_generator():
    pool = range(10)
    return choice(pool), choice(pool)


def q_generator():
    pair = pair_generator()

    # случайный оператор - случайный ключ словаря
    op = choice(tuple(operations.keys()))

    # результат математического выражения и признак смены местами операндов
    res, switch_flag = operations.get(op)(*pair)

    return '{0} {2} {1} = {3}'.format(*(pair if not switch_flag else reversed(pair)), op, res)


 # карта связей "символ - оператор" с соответствующими обертками
operations = {'+': noop_wrap(add), '-': switcher(sub), '*': noop_wrap(mul), '/': switcher(truediv)}


for _ in range(5):
    print(q_generator())
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ценную информацию!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def generate_math_question(a,b) -> str:
    operator = '+','-','*','/'
    rand = random.choice(operator)
    return f'{a} {rand} {b}'

print(generate_math_question(a=random.randint(1,10),b=random.randint(1,10)))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]